# Assigning a list of meeting times to meeting rooms

Tags: python, algorithm, heap

Given a list of meetings time blocks I'm trying to allocate them to meeting rooms (while using the least amount of rooms). It works fairly well but it returns the incorrect value sometimes and I can't figure out why.

```
from typing import List, Tuple
import heapq

def offer(begin:int, end:int, heap:List[int]) -> int:
    while heap and heap[0] <= begin:
        heapq.heappop(heap)
    heapq.heappush(heap, end)
    return len(heap)


def schedule(times:List[Tuple[int, int]]):
    heap = []
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for begin, end in sorted(times):
        key = offer(begin, end, heap)
        groups[key].append( (begin, end))
    
    return groups
```

#### 1) Successful Test:

```
times = [(12, 13), (12, 15), (17, 20)]
assert schedule(times) == [(1, (12, 13)), (2, (12, 15)), (1, (17, 20))] # works
```

[image: test-case-1]

#### 2) Successful Test:

A more complex case.

[image: case-2]

```
times = [(12,13), (13,15), (17,20), (13,14), (19 , 21), (18, 20), (12,13)] 
assert schedule(vals) == {
    1: [(12, 13), (13,14),(17, 20)],
    2: [(12, 13), (13, 15), (18, 20),],
    3: [(19, 21)],
} # works
```

#### 3) Unsuccessful

[image: case-3]

Seems simple enough but fails

```
times =  [(12, 16), (15,18), (17,20)]
assert schedule(times) == {
    1: [(12, 16), (17,20)],
    2: [(15,18)],
} # error
```

Instead it allocates two meetings to the second room that clearly overlap:
`defaultdict(list, {1: [(12, 16)], 2: [(15, 18), (17, 20)]})`

Comment: Have you done any debugging? If so, what did you find? If not, I suggest adding `print()` statements to see what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not tracking which rooms are currently free. Your code for 'offer' assumes that if there is 1 room being used (i.e. `len(heap)==1`), that it is always the first room. To fix this, track which rooms are free:

```py
def offer(begin: int, end: int, heap: List[Tuple[int, int]], free_rooms: List[int]) -> int:
    while heap and heap[0][0] <= begin:
        free_rooms.append(heapq.heappop(heap)[1])
    if not free_rooms:
        some_free_room = len(heap) + 1
    else:
        some_free_room = free_rooms.pop()
    heapq.heappush(heap, (end, some_free_room))
    return some_free_room


def schedule(times: List[Tuple[int, int]]):
    heap = []
    free_rooms = []
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for begin, end in sorted(times):
        key = offer(begin, end, heap, free_rooms)
        groups[key].append((begin, end))

    return groups
```

This code may still fail some of those tests. The reason is that there is more than one way to schedule while allocating the fewest rooms; you are checking against a specific allocation. If you also want the property that we should greedily use the first free room, you'll need another heap:

```py
def offer_first_free(begin: int, end: int, heap: List[Tuple[int, int]], free_rooms: List[int]) -> int:
    while heap and heap[0][0] <= begin:
        heapq.heappush(free_rooms, heapq.heappop(heap)[1])
    if not free_rooms:
        first_free_room = len(heap) + 1
    else:
        first_free_room = heapq.heappop(free_rooms)
    heapq.heappush(heap, (end, first_free_room))
    return first_free_room
```